# Visual Studio 2008 unit tests and nunit

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, unit-testing, nunit

When you right click on a method in a code file in Visual Studio 2008 you get this
[image]
which creates the unit test skeleton for that method.

Is there a way (by means of a template change or some nifty hack) by which I can change this to create unit tests based on [Nunit](http://www.nunit.org/index.php) rather than [Visual Studio unit testing tools](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms379625.aspx)?
Something like this…

```
using System.Collections;
using NUnit.Framework;

    namespace Domain.UnitTest
    {
      [TestFixture]
      public class ManagerTest
      {
        [Test]
        public void SomethingTest()
        {
          string expected = null;
          string acutal = Something.Create();
          Assert.AreEqual(expected, acutal);
        }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try modifying the file `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE\ItemTemplatesCache\CSharp\1033\SimpleUnitTest.zip\SimpleUnitTest.cs` (after making a backup, of course).  Keep a copy of your updated version elsewhere as this may get overwritten by updates.

FWIW -- I found this by searching for the string `using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;` inside files starting at the top level directory of the VS application directory.

Comment: I tried this and it works when creating a unit test in the Test Project itself. However, if I right click on the method I want to create a test for, it generates the test without my modifications. Any ideas why this might be or how to fix it? Cheers.